# Help with Runge-Kutta method for solving systems of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am currently doing an investigation with SIR model for predicting the progress of an infectious disease. However, I am not very much familiar with systems of differential equations,so I would need some help. Some basic tips/steps on the path of solving my system would be very helpful, since it involves three equations and my mathematics knowledge is not advanced enough.

dS/dt=-a*S*I    where a is a constant
dI/dt=a*S*I-b*I           where b is another constant
dR/dt=b*I

I am not expecting anyone to solve the problem for me, but I'd appreciate some tips and basic steps in how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

You solve it just like a single differential equation, but you have a vector value and its derivative.  Your equation becomes $$\begin {pmatrix}S\\I\\R \end {pmatrix}'=\begin {pmatrix}-aSI\\aSI-bI\\bI \end {pmatrix}$$  Just plug that into your Runge-Kutta stepper. Note that $I'=-(S+R)'$ ,so $R+S+I$ is a constant.  You can use that to eliminate one variable.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can see that the third equation is decoupled from the first two, i.e

$$R = b \int_0^t I(\tau) d \tau + constant$$

Special cases:

If $a=0$ you get $S=constant$ from the first equation, and

$$I = C_0 e^{-bt}$$
$$R = -C_0 e^{-bt} + C_1$$

If $b=0$ you get $R=constant$ from the third equation, and

$$S = C_0 \frac{e^{C_0 t + C_1}}{1-ae^{C_0 t + C_1}}$$
$$I= - S $$

$C_0$ and $C_1$ are constants to be determined from the initial conditions.

**Analytical solution:**

If $a \neq 0$ and $b \neq 0$ you can differentiate the first equation with respect to $t$, and substitute with the second equation to get a second-order nonlinear ODE for $S$:

$$S \frac{d^2 S}{d t^2}=\left( \frac{dS}{dt} \right)^2+aS^2 \frac{dS}{dt}-bS\frac{dS}{dt}$$

and for $I$

$$I \frac{d^2 I}{d t^2}=\left( \frac{dI}{dt} \right)^2-aI^2 \frac{dI}{dt}-bI\frac{dI}{dt} + b \frac{dI}{dt} -abI^2$$

Comparing them shows $S=-I$ if $b=0$. $S=constant$ is one possible solution, in which case $I=0$. The equation which gives $S$ is autonomous, i.e. the independent variable is missing, therefore you can apply the method described in Zwillinger - Handbook of differential equations p. 230. You substitute with $u(S)=dS/dt$ to get

$$S u \frac{du}{dS}=u^2+aS^2 u-bSu$$

The trivial solution of $u$ is $u=0$ ($S=constant$). If $u \neq 0$

$$\frac{dS}{dt}=u=C_0 S + a S^2 - b S \log(S)$$

You can determine $C_0$ from the initial conditions. We have reduced the ODE to first order. We can express the solution in implicit form:

$$\int \frac{1}{C_0 S + a S^2 - b S log(S)} dS = t + C_1$$

I could not find any closed form primitive function. You can get explicit solution if either $a$ or $b$ is small in some sense. In this case you can apply perturbation methods.

**Numerical solution:**

If you have access to Matlab, you can easily apply the ode45 function, in which the Runge-Kutta method is implemented. You can also do it in Excel, but this way requires a little more effort from you. The advantage of the analytical approach is that now you can apply the Runge-Kutta method (RK45) for a single equation, therefore you can separate the effect of $a$ and $b$. You can find many examples of implementations of the RK45, one is [here](https://controls.engin.umich.edu/wiki/index.php/ExcelModelingODE).